# Using ES6, what is the cleanest way to reassign properties in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, es6-modules

Say I have an object as follows:

```
const data = {
  title: 'firstStackOverFlowQuestion!',
  id: '100',
  datePosted: '04-10-2022',
  options: [
    {
      questionId: 1,
      difficultyLevel: 1,
      difficultyScale: 10,
      complexity: 2,
      complexityScale: 10,
    },
    {
      questionId: 2,
      difficultyLevel: 4,
      difficultyScale: 10,
      complexity: 3,
      complexityScale: 10,
    },
    {
      questionId: 3,
      difficultyLevel: 8,
      difficultyScale: 10,
      complexity: 6,
      complexityScale: 10,
    },
  ]
}
```

What is the cleanest way to reduce the options array to just two properties, to show the below:

```
const data = {
  title: 'firstStackOverFlowQuestion',
  id: '100',
  datePosted: '04-10-2022',
  options: [
    {
      questionId: 1,
      difficultyLevel: 1,
    },
    {
      questionId: 2,
      difficultyLevel: 4,
    },
    {
      questionId: 3,
      difficultyLevel: 8,
    },
  ],
```

}

Any suggestions would be most welcome! I imagine mapping, reducing, and /or using the spread operator would offer the cleanest solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `map` + `...` (spread):

```js
const result = {
   ...data,
   options: data.options.map(
     ({questionId, difficultyLevel}) => ({questionId, difficultyLevel})
   )
}
```

Comment: Clean as a whistle! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` along with destructuring.

```
data.options = data.options.map(
    ({questionId, difficultyLevel}) => ({questionId, difficultyLevel})
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the quick response